# Is accessing a struct within a struct by pointers undefined behavior?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, strict-aliasing, type-punning

I have a `struct A` that contains a `struct B` and I access `A` via a pointer `pa` and `b` via pointer `ba`. Is this undefined behavior (Strict Aliasing Rule)? (The `struct B` part is not accessed by the pointer to `struct A` `pa`.)
Note that there is no cast but still there are pointers of different types referring to the same memory.

```
struct B {int x;};
struct A { int foo; struct B b; int bar;};
struct A global_a = { 1, { 2 }, 3 };
struct A * get_ptr_to_struct_A()
{
        return &global_a;
}
void modify_struct_B(struct B * p)
{
        p->x++;
}
int main()
{
    struct A local_A;
    struct A * pa = get_ptr_to_struct_A();
    struct B * pb = &pa->b;
    local_A = *pa; // First assignment
    modify_struct_B(pb);
    local_A = *pa;  // 2nd assignment. Can the compiler chose to skip this?
}
```

According to the strict aliasing rule, the compiler can assume that pointers of different types do not point to the same memory. Hence, the compiler can draw the conclusion that the second assignment is meaningless and optimize it away. (I.e. it assumes that the pointer pb points somewhere where the pointer pa does not point.)
What prevents the compiler from ignoring the second assignment?

Comment: Why would having 2 pointers to the same thing be undefined behavior?

Comment: `pa` is a pointer to `global_a`, and `pb` is a pointer to `global_a.b`. Both are valid pointers.

Comment: It's fine, there's nothing undefined about it.  You can also access the structures both directly (without pointers) and indirectly (with pointers), and it's still well-defined.

Comment: The only time way having two pointers to the same object could be UB is if one of them is declared `restrict`. That means (roughly) that it's the only pointer in the current scope that can be used to modify the object.

Comment: Thank so much for answers! I am confused..I thought that 'strict aliasing'  means that it is UB to have two pointers of different types that point at the same memory, right? Have I misunderstood something? This is why I suspected that my example contains UB.

Comment: Strict aliasing rule allows for accessing a member of a struct ... otherwise it would be impossible to use structs

Comment: @ScottHunter I think it is the strict aliasing rule that comes into play here.

Comment: @gregspears No, the struct A cotains a struct B, not at ponter to struct B.

Comment: @M.M Of course it is possible to access struct elements but here I access the same memory area with two pointers of different types which in my view seems to violate the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: @ReotardoDaVinci you access an object with correct type for that object ... in any `&a->b` you have pointers of type `A` and `B` involved

Comment: @Barmar I do not agree with your comment (probably due to my own lack of understanding). As I understand it, the strict aliasing rule says that the compiler can assume that two pointers of different types do not point to the same memory. But I have two pointers of different types that point to the same memory. How can not that be UB?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is not undefined behavior.

Why?

```c
  struct A * pa = get_ptr_to_struct_A();
```

`pa` points to `global_a` which contains `foo=0`, `b.x=0`, and `bar=0`.

```c
  struct B * pb = &(pa->b);
```

Now `pb` points to (has the address of) `global_a.b`.

```c
  modify_struct_B(pb);
```

You are passing a valid pointer to an instance of `struct B` (`pb->x=0`).

```c
void modify_struct_B(struct B * p)
{
        p->x++;
}
```

It just increments `pb->x`, so after this, `pb->x=1`.

Every step is deterministic and there is no room for the compiler to implement something different.

The strict aliasing rule is not at play here because you are not aliasing anything since you are not reinterpreting or casting any pointer.

In https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object, it states that is about interpreting `T2` reference as a `T1` reference.

> **Strict aliasing**
>
> Given an object with effective type T1, using an lvalue expression (typically, dereferencing a pointer) of a different type T2 is undefined behavior

So you would have undefined behavior if:

- b was the first element in `struct A`
- and, you assigned:

```c
struct B * pb = (struct A *)pa;
```

Comment: If I elaborate the example, could it not reveal UB? The strict aliasing rule states that the compiler can assume that pointers of different types do not point at the same memory. If I copy the struct A twice, once before the call to modify_struct_B() and then again after, cannot the compiler skip the second copying? (It assumes that the memory is unmodified since no pointer that points to struct A has been dereferenced and hence the struct A is unchanged.)

Comment: Reading a bit more, the strict aliasing rule is about two pointer of different type pointing to the same address, in your example, `b` is not in the same address as `a`, since it has an int before.

But even if it were, the rule is about reinterpreting or casting, but it is not what your code does.

It would be different if you defined `b` as the first field of `struct A`, AND then cast an `struct A` pointer to a `struct B` pointer.

Comment: I just updated the response with that info. Hope it answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no undefined behavior in the examples posted.  There is no problem using pointers to point to structure members such as `pb`, you could also have a pointer to the `x` member of `*pb`:

```
    int *pi = &pb->x;
```

What you must be careful about is the life time of the objects pointed to by these pointers.  If the object goes out of scope, the pointers become invalid, they are *dangling pointers* and dereferencing them for reading or writing has undefined behavior.

Here is an example:

```
struct B { int x; };
struct A { int foo; struct B b; int bar; };

struct A global_a = { 0 };

struct A *get_ptr_to_struct_A()
{
    return &global_a;
}

void modify_struct_B(struct B *p)
{
    p->x++;
}

int main()
{
    struct A *pa = get_ptr_to_struct_A();
    struct B *pb = &pa->b;

    modify_struct_B(pb); // no problem 

    {
        struct A local_a;
        pa = &A;
        pb = &pa->b;
        modify_struct_B(pb); // no problem
    }

    modify_struct_B(pb); // undefined behavior. local_a has gone out of scope
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: N1570 6.5 paragraph 7 lists the types of lvalue that may be used to access the stored value of a structure-type object.  Although it allows the stored value of such an object to be accessed an lvalue of an *enclosing* structure type, I see nothing that would require that an implementation accommodate the possibility of using a member-type lvalue to access a structure member, beyond the fact that failure to do so would be excessively obtuse for even the most aggressive "optimizing" compiler writer.

Answer (score 0):

Given the definitions:

```
struct s {int x[2]; };
struct t {struct s sv[2]; };
struct u {struct t tv[2]; };
```

the Standard specifies in N1570 6.5p7 the types of lvalue that may be used to access the stored value of an object of type `struct t`.  In particular, the storage may be accessed using lvalues of type `t`, `u`, or other structures containing a member of type `struct t`, or qualified variations of those types.  The list of allowable types would *not* `struct s` nor `int`.

Obviously arrays within structures would be rather useless if one couldn't use any lvalues of the element types to access their members.  There are at least two ways of resolving this problem:

1. Treat accesses of the form `someStruct.member` and `someStruct.arrayTypeMember[index]` as though the storage is being accessed "by" an lvalue of the structure type, even though that would contradict the part of the Standard that says the latter form is equivalent to `*(someStruct.arrayTypeMember+index)`.  Both clang and gcc seem to do this.
2. Treat the Standard as allowing structures' stored values to be accessed by lvalues of member type that have no apparent relation to any containing structure type.  Clang and gcc seem to do this as well.
3. Treat any pointer which is freshly visibly derived from the address of an object of some other type as being capable, at least within the context of such derivation, of accessing storage of the type from which it was derived.

Under interpretation #3, a compiler given e.g.

```
struct writeThingie {int len,size; int *dat; } *it;
... and then within some loop
if (it->len < it->size)
  it->dat[it->len++] = something;
```

would only need to accommodate the possibility that the assignment might modify the value of it->size if something within the function took the address of member `len` of a structure `writeThingie` and could have caused it to be stored in `it->dat`.

I think it would have been considered obvious and non-controversial that code should be able to use an lvalue of the form `structPtr->array[index]` to access an element of an array-type member of the pointer's target type, but different compilers would have achieved that result via different means, and no single set of rules could accurately describe them all.  Instead, the Standard waived jurisdiction on the assumption that compiler writers would try to satisfy programmers' needs.